# Why does the "Interesting" category of questions not appear on the Questions page?

Tags: discussion, interesting-page

When I look for questions to answer for a long time I clicked the big `Questions` button. That made sense to me. It was very difficult to find questions that I am actually interested in, even though I used the *favorite tags* and *hide unwanted tags* features.

At some point I figured out, that if you just enter https://stackoverflow.com/, you get the category "Interesting", which is far superior to `Questions`. Is there a reason why the "Interesting" category does not appear when clicking on `Questions`?

Comment: It seems to be misleading and/or confusing: stackoverflow.com shows questions but with different options than stackoverflow.com/questions? The same on meta.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/221214/interesting-tab-on-stackoverflow

Comment: @gnat So its a duplicate... I swear I searched for it before I posted. Should I delete it?

Comment: @gnat I don't think it is a duplicate. The question is the *Why?* Would like to know that

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194476/someone-flagged-my-question-as-already-answered-but-its-not

Comment: It took me a couple of months to realise the "Interesting" page existed.

Comment: I'm confused, how can something be "hidden" when it is clearly displayed on the main page?

Comment: Related: [Adding the "Interesting" tab to the Questions Page](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87470/)

Comment: Do you mean it's hidden on the **Questions** page?  The main page certainly has it, it's my default view.

Comment: @BenVoigt There is some weird grammar going on here. "I have hidden the stone in my pocket" == "The category is hidden on the main page". I am not a native speaker though, if you have a suggestion to clarify it go ahead. Maybe "hidden from the question page".

Comment: @nwp: Ok, that is a grammatically correct, if weird, way to read it.  I've now changed the title to something unambiguous.

Comment: @BenVoigt That kind of ruined the joke though. But I guess understandability has a higher priority than trying to be funny.

Comment: You can simply click the SO logo from any page to get the interesting questions page so there is no need for an extra tab.